# Should I commit /bin directory when working with virtualenv?

Tags: python, git, project, virtualenv, setuptools

I am starting my first actual python project. I follow "Learn Python the Hard Way" to make an initial [Python skeleton](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex46.html) and I am using virtualenv too.

Now I want to use git to do the version control. According to some previous questions in SO, I am not suggested to commit any virtualenv files. Instead, I could use `pip freeze > requirements.txt`, and use `.gitignore` to ignore the virtualenv directories.

However, both virtualenv and Python project skeleton require a `/bin` directory, should I commit it as well? (Actually I don't really know what the role `/bin` is playing in Python project)

Any suggestions are appreciated, if there is something wrong with my process to set up a Python project, please correct me.

Comment: `pip freeze > requirements` is enough is enough to save the state of the virtual environment. The virtualenv setup uses absolute paths on your system, so your project wouldn't work for someone who cloned it on their system using your `/bin` from a git clone, so it's best to ignore all the `virtualenv` content including the `/bin` directory when committing. BTW, The `/bin` directory is created by `virtualenv` to contain the `python` executable that it uses to run your project on your system. So you can safely ignore the `/bin` directory when committing to git as `virtualenv` re-creates it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`yourproject/bin` is distinct from `yourproject/env/bin`, where `yourproject/env` is the virtual environment's directory (and neither of them is `/bin` in the root directory). You should ignore everything in `env`, and indeed, your project should work for someone who isn't using a virtual environment, or is managing it differently. Otherwise, you lose the benefits.

Let's imagine for a second that you finish your project, and I want to use it for a new task. I start a new project with a virtualenv of its own, and install some other components I want to use, and then yours. Oops, now I have an older version of Python than I started out with, and that bug in `deactivate` from two years ago somehow got resurrected. Imagine debugging that, let alone the annoyance of finding that your project replaced some files of mine.

(As these things go, the `bin` directory is a pretty static part of the virtual environment; zapping other parts of my private `env` would be much more destructive. If you committed `lib` you would have prevented me from installing any other components before yours.)